# Why won't my commands work in Bash?

Tags: bash

[image: Screen shot]

Please check out my screen shot, I've tried entering commands but it keeps saying command not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see a screen shot :(

Comment: So far, there is no screen shot.  Posting text would be better, anyway.

Comment: You're entering $ at the start of the command. Remove the '$' from whatever you're copying and pasting

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to precede each command with `$`. When you see something like `$ pwd` in a post, the `$` just represents a generic prompt; you don't actually type it, just the command that follows it.

The error is telling you that `$` is not a command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help